# Welchem Zweck dient "einem" hier?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Wer niemals heimlich beim Schein einer Taschenlampe unter der
>   Bettdecke gelesen hat, weil Vater oder Mutter oder sonst irgendeine
>   besorgte Person **einem** **das Licht** ausknipste mit der gutgemeinten
>   Begründung, man müsse jetzt schlafen, da man doch morgen so früh aus
>   den Federn sollte -

"Einem" scheint unverbunden zu sein. Warum? Könnte es "for someone" übersetzt wird/bedeutet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinngemäß bezieht sich "einem" auf "wer", das ganz am Anfang steht. Der Satz wäre auch ohne "einem" korrekt, hätte aber ein bisschen andere Bedeutung.

Durch "einem" wird vermittelt, dass Vater oder Mutter das Licht nur für die gesagte Person ausschalten, z.B. nur im Kinderzimmer, selbst aber weiterhin in einem anderen Raum bei Licht sitzen.

Wäre der Satz ohne "einem", hätte er die Bedeutung, dass das Licht für alle ausgeschaltet wird, nicht nur fürs Kind.

Answer (score 3):

Hier werden Indefinitpronomen https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinitpronomen verwendet. In dem Beispielsatz sind das "Wer", "einem" und "man".

Man vermeidet dadurch eine bestimmte Person oder Gruppe spezifizieren zu müssen.

Das ist wie im Englischen in "One can't deny the fact ..."